# When checking a Bitcoin block, why do you get a leading prefix of zeros once you find the correct nonce?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bitcoin, blockchain

I have recently been looking into Bitcoin and the proof of work system.

In this system, when mining, a user has a "challenge string" that they need to concatenate with the CORRECT "proof string"(nonce) and hash, the outcome of that hash starts with a prefix of leading zeros and that's how they verify the block.

My question is, when combining that "challenge string" and the CORRECT "proof string"(nonce), why does the corresponding hash of those values start with the prefix of zeros? How does that work?

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question makes more sense on [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/), where it's probably already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of "Challenge string" and "proof of string" is sent to a hashing function, which is a one way function and results in a "random string" (The condition on "random string" is that it should have x number of zeroes in the beginning. The difficulty of guessing increases day to day, which is nothing but x increases).

The job of a Miner is to guess the "proof of string" until the condition on the "random string" is met.

So, it is a pure guessing game. GPUs are very good at generating random numbers very quickly. That is why miners around the world are using top class GPUs to mine the bitcoin transactions.

Comment: So is the only way that it’s verifying that the block is authentic is by using the correct challenge string? Which is derived from the version, transaction merkle root, time stamp and previous block hash?

Comment: Technically, yes. But a lot of information lies in the Merkle root. 
Another verification which the miner does to check if the transactions in a block are valid or not is by checking if the sum of the unspent transaction outputs of the sender's account is not lesser than the amount of tokens he is spending in the current transaction.
But this is not the computationally tough job. It can be done by day-to-day CPUS. The tough part lies in the guessing part.

Comment: Do the records in a blockchain just contain the version, nonce, transaction merkle root, time stamp and previous block hash? and if so, do miners know where to grab the next set of transactions due to the timestamp?

Or do they contain the transaction information of each transaction?

Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Yes, you can see a sample block here: https://blockexplorer.com/block/000000000000000000c5b76c6c521b34b843a4282f39972e0dab07713bccf339. 
Every transaction will be broadcasted to the miners network. These transactions will first go into the transaction pool of each miner. Once in ten minutes (for bitcoin) these miners will pick random transactions which will fit in 1MB block size and then validate them.

Comment: So the old transaction information(to be checked) is held in the persons wallet and each blocks information is held within the blockchain? So the blocks and transaction information is kept in two separate places.

Comment: No, as I said earlier every transaction made will be broadcasted to the entire bitcoin network. Each one will hold all the un-verified transactions in a transaction pool. You can see the current un-verified transactions here: https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions.
Finally, to clarify transaction pool is different from blockchain. These both are held by miners. The person's wallet has nothing to do once the transaction is broadcasted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160133/discussion-between-adam-moffat-and-anirudh-alampally).

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to Bitcoin but Bitcoin uses the same mechanism, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash for a description of how Proof Of Work "works" and why it works that way.

The short answer is that you are creating a hash collision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance) and the more leading zeros there are the more difficult it is to create the collision.

In Bitcoin, the difficulty is algorithmically chosen based on the compute on the bitcoin network. This typically only goes up, but should the compute go down the dificulty will also go down. The algorithm adjusts dificulty to keep transaction verification time around 10 minutes.

Comment: "the fewer leading zeros there are the more difficult it is to create the collision" - I thought this was the other way around?

Comment: Your right, wrote that late, edited; the more zeros mean a lower space of possible solutions and hence harder problem.